# Extract further posts from RSS feed to CSV using R

Tags: asp.net, r, parsing, rss

I am trying to extract data from an RSS feed at the following url http://live.reuters.com/Event/rss.aspx?id=70335. Essentially I want to extract the title and date of each post using the code outlined in this post: [Parse RSS feed using XML packagin R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467783/parse-rss-feed-using-xml-packagin-r)

The code itself is

```
 library(XML)
library(RCurl)

###Extracting Data from Reuters
xml.url <- "http://live.reuters.com/Event/rss.aspx?id=70335"
script  <- getURL(xml.url)
doc     <- xmlParse(script)
titles    <- xpathSApply(doc,'//item/title',xmlValue)
pubdates <- xpathSApply(doc,'//item/pubDate',xmlValue)
reuters<-cbind(titles, pubdates)
reuters_data<-data.frame(reuters)

 #Exporting as a csv
write.csv(reuters_data, file = "reuters_post.csv")
```

The code does almost exactly what I want it do. However, the problem I am running into is that it only extracts the first 45 posts. I know there are closer to 1000 posts. Does this have something to do with rss.aspx format? Is there a workaround so that I can get all the posts in the RSS feed, and not just the first 45? Any help would be much appreciated, since I am a newcomer to data scraping.

Thanks,
Thomas

Comment: Seems like a limitation set by the CMS system that they are using rather than something wrong with R. You may have to parse the pages themselves if you want everything by going through each of http://live.reuters.com/Event/Conflict_on_the_Gaza_Strip?Page=XX

Answer (score 1):

It addresses the issue of RSS/Atom feeds which do not allow for historical information to be retrieved, see [How Do I Fetch All Old Items on an RSS Feed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576552/how-do-i-fetch-all-old-items-on-an-rss-feed)

However, we can use unofficial Google Reader API [GoogleReaderAPI Wiki](https://code.google.com/p/pyrfeed/wiki/GoogleReaderAPI).

```
library(RCurl)
library(RJSONIO)

N <- 100 # Number of items to fetch
url <- paste("http://www.google.com/reader/api/0/stream/contents/feed/http://live.reuters.com/Event/rss.aspx%3Fid=70335?n=", N, sep="")

json <- getURL(url)                               # Fetches data
list <- fromJSON(json)                            # JSON to list
df   <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, list$items)) # list to data.frame

title    <- unlist(df$title)                                                # Title
datetime <- as.POSIXlt(unlist(df$published), origin="1970-01-01", tz="GMT") # Publication date

reuters <- data.frame(title, datetime)        # Output data.frame
write.csv(reuters, file = "reuters_post.csv") # Writes CSV
```