# Pull full text from RSS Feed using R XML package

Tags: xml, r, rss, full-text-search

Hi I'am currently trying to pull full text from the RSS feed: http://www.hu-berlin.de/pr/nachrichten.rss?cat=exz. Displayed are only a short description and the link to the full text:

```
<item>
    <guid>http://www.hu-berlin.de/pr/nachrichten/nr1305/nr_130524_00</guid>
     <title>KOSMOS Summer University 2013 </title>
     <link>http://www.hu-berlin.de/pr/nachrichten/nr1305/nr_130524_00</link>
     <description>Frist verlÃ¤ngert: Anmeldung zum internationalen Forschertreffen bis 30. Juni mÃ¶glich</description>
     <pubDate>Thu, 20 Jun 2013 00:00:00 +0200</pubDate>
  </item>
```

I can get it exactely like that to R using `xmlTreeParse`

I was wondering weather it is possible to pull the full text directly in R using the XML library I found this: [Parse RSS feed using XML packagin R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467783/parse-rss-feed-using-xml-packagin-r) and while it works fine its not helpful regarding the fulltext issue. I found rss-to-full-texr converters (like:http://fulltextrssfeed.com/) which is exactly what i need but i couldn't how they achieve this. Maybe this will help other people looking for the same thing or nobody needs to research this because its so basic in that case I'm very sorry I troubled you.
I'd appreciate any help or helpful links!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full text *isnt in* the RSS feed XML data. You have to get the link, get that web page, and then parse that using R's HTML parsing tools, well-described elsewhere.

RSS is designed to be a summary format, then humans are supposed to go to the web page.